# Min sum of distances (absolute differences) between array element and set of k array elements

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, heap, dynamic-programming

I need to find the minimum sum of the distances between an element in the array and the set of k-elements of the array, not including that index.

For example:

arr = {5, 7, 4, 9}

k = 2

min_sum(5) = |5-4| + |5-7| = 3

min_sum(7) = |7-9| + |7-5| = 4

min_sum(4) = |4-5| + |4-7| = 4

min_sum(9) = |9-7| + |9-5| = 6

So, a naive solution would be to subtract the i-th element from each element of the array, then sort the array and calculate the sum of the first k elements in the sorted array. But it takes too long... I believe this is a dp-problem or something like that (maybe treaps).

Input:

n - number of array elements

k - number of elements in a set

array

Constraints:

2 <= n <= 350 000

1 <= k < n

1 <= a[i] <= 10^9

time limit: 2 seconds

Input:

4

2

5 7 4 9

Output:

3 4 4 6

What is the most efficient way to solve this problem? How to optimize the search for the minimum sum?

This is my code in C++, and it works about 3 mins for n = 350 000, k = 150 000:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int n, k, tp;
    unsigned long long temp;
    cin >> n >> k;

    vector<unsigned int> org;
    vector<unsigned int> a;
    vector<unsigned long long> cum(n, 0);
    //unordered_map <int, long long> ans;
    unordered_map <int, long long> mp;


    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cin >> tp;
        org.push_back(tp);
        a.push_back(tp);
    }

/*
    srand(time(0));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        org.push_back(rand());
        a.push_back(org[i]);
    }
*/

    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    partial_sum(a.begin(), a.end(), cum.begin());

    mp[a[0]] = cum[k] - cum[0] - a[0] * k;
    //ans[a[0]] = mp[a[0]];

    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
       mp[a[i]] = a[i] * i - cum[i-1] + cum[k] - cum[i] - a[i] * (k-i);
    }

    for (int i = 1; i < n-k; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <= k; j++){
            //if (ans.find(a[i+j]) != ans.end()) {continue;}
            temp = ( (a[i+j] * j) - (cum[i+j-1] - cum[i-1]) ) + ( cum[i+k] - cum[i+j] - a[i+j] * (k-j) );
            if (mp.find(a[i+j]) == mp.end()) { mp[a[i+j]] = temp; }
            else if (mp[a[i+j]] > temp) { mp[a[i+j]] = temp; }
            //else { ans[a[i+j]] = mp[a[i+j]]; }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << mp[org[i]] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *What is the most efficient way to solve this problem? How to optimize the search for the minimum sum?* -- Honestly, what's the purpose of showing code that, as you even state, is inefficient?  This is a pure algorithms question, and little to do with C++.

Comment: If the tag on the question was only `algorithm`, then there wouldn't be an issue of not posting code, because this is not a "code" question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can solve this problem efficiently by taking the sliding window approach.

It seems safe to assume that there are no duplicates in the array. If it contains duplicates, then we can simply discard them with the help of `HashSet`.

The next step is to sort the array to guarantee that the closest k elements will be within the window `[i - k; i + k]` for each index i.

We will keep three variables for the window: `left`, `right` and `currentSum`. They will be adjusted accordingly at each iteration. Initially, `left = 0` and `right = k`(since the element at index 0 doesn't have elements to its left) and `currentSum = result` for index 0.

The key consideration is that the variables left and right are unlikely to change 'significantly' during the iteration. To be more precise, at each iteration we should attempt to move the window to the right by comparing the distances `nums[i + right + 1] - nums[i]` vs `nums[i] - nums[i - left]`. (You can prove mathematically that there is no point in trying to move the window to the left.) If the former is less than the latter, we increment right and decrement left while updating currentSum at the same time.

In order to recalculate currentSum, I would suggest writing down expressions for two adjacent iterations and looking closer at the difference between them.
For instance, if
`result[i] = nums[i + 1] + ... + nums[i + right] - (nums[i - 1] + ... + nums[i - left]) + (left - right) * nums[i],` then
`result[i] = nums[i + 2] + ... + nums[i + right] - (nums[i] + ... + nums[i - left]) + (left - right + 2) * nums[i + 1]`.
As we can see, these expressions are quite similar. The time complexity of this solution is `O(n * log(n))`. (my solution in Java for `n ~ 500_000` and `k ~ 400_000` works within 300 ms) I hope this together with the consideration above will help you.

Assuming that we have sorted the original array `nums` and computed the mapping `element->its index in the sorted array`(for instance, through binary search), we can proceed with finding the distances.

```
public long[] findMinDistances(int[] nums, int k) {
    long[] result = new long[nums.length];
    long currentSum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++) {
        currentSum += nums[i];
    }
    result[0] = currentSum - (long) k * nums[0];

    int left = 0;
    int right = k;
    currentSum = result[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++) {
        int current = nums[i];
        int previous = nums[i - 1];
        currentSum -= (long) (left - right) * previous;
        currentSum -= previous;

        if (right >= 1) {
            currentSum -= current;
            left++;
            right--;
        } else {
            currentSum += nums[i - 1 - left];
        }
        currentSum += (long) (left - right) * current;

        while (i + right + 1 < nums.length && i - left >= 0 &&
                nums[i + right + 1] - current < current - nums[i - left]) {
            currentSum += nums[i + right + 1] - current;
            currentSum -= current - nums[i - left];
            right++;
            left--;
        }
        result[i] = currentSum;
    }
    return result;
}
```

For every element `e` in the original array its minimal sum of distances will be `result[mapping.get(e)]`.

Comment: Duplicates should not be discarded because we have to calculate the distances to them too. In my solution above, I've implemented something similar to your description. Apparently, I recalculate the sum for a long time. I can't figure out how you managed to get O( log(n) ) for the sliding window. You are free to post your solution in your answer or post a link to the code. This is ok for these tags. And thanks for your efforts.

Comment: I got the concept of a sliding window. I tried to implement this, but now my solution in C++ for `n=350000` and `k=150000` works within 6-7 seconds. Could you please post a link to your Java solution that runs in 300ms?

Comment: @OliverWayne I have just updated my answer. It turns out it works, whether an array contains duplicates or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one is better:

Sort the array first then you can know that fact -
For every element i in the array the k minimum distances of it with other elemets will be the distances with the ones that in k places around it in the array.
(of course it's maybe to the right or to the left or from both sides).

So for every element i to calculate min_sum(a[i]) do that:

First, min_sum(a[i]) = 0.

Then, go with two indexes, let's mark them r (to the right of i) and l (to the left of i)
and compare the distance (a[i]-a[r]) with the distance (a[i]-a[l]).
You will add the smallest to min_sum(a[i]) and if it was the right one then
increas index r, and if it was the left one then decrease index l.
Of course if the left got to 0 or the right one got to n you will most take the distaces with elemets from the other side.
Anyway you do that till you sum k elemets and that's it.

This way you didn't sort any thing but the main array.

Comment: Yes, and I did something like this in my C ++ solution in the problem description, but it works for O(N*K). N and K can be up to 10^5, so N*K = 10^10, it's too many operations. I need an algorithm that works for O(n*log(k)) or O(n*log^2(k)).